# Highstock - Draw Line on yAxis in front of the chart

Tags: highcharts

In this example [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr2ha/).

The Line appear behind the chart.

Is it possible to draw the line in front of the chart?

Thank you for your help?

**The code:**

```
(function() {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    chart: {
    },

    yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0.696,
            width: 5,
            color: 'green',
            dashStyle: 'dash',
            label: {
                text: 'Latest value',
                align: 'right',
                y: 12,
                x: 0
            }
        }]
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
       type: 'area',
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `plotLine` `zIndex` property.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.plotLines.zIndex

Comment: What is the value i should add in `zIndex` ? I've tried any value but it seems doesn't change anything.